# Selenium Chromedriver fails to fill password correctly

Tags: vba, selenium, ms-access

I am accessing a Webpage containing details for a given order for automatically populating this order in my own database.

Initially I started with the Edgedriver, but it appears that Edge is not able to download a file if the link has a graphic as overlay (it only asks if I want to save the pictures - tips for solving this issue are welcome, too...). Normally I use Firefox as the least nosy browser, but the Geckodriver doesn't work with VBA.

So I switched to Chromedriver which now produces the following strange error:

When I send the correct password via "SendKeys", the result is "Bad Credentials". Entering the identical password directly in the field and then let Chromedriver pressing "Click" works.

```
    .Get "https://my-website.com"

    .FindElementById("username").Clear   ' login
    .FindElementById("password").Clear
    .FindElementById("username").SendKeys Trim(UserName)
    .FindElementById("password").SendKeys Trim(Password)    'The content in the password field must be somehow different to the text entered via keyboard ***

    .FindElementByClass("login").Click
```

Any help is appreciated

Used applications:
Windows 10 Pro (64 Bit), Access 2016, Chrome 83.0.4103.97 (64 Bit), Chromedriver 83.0.4103.39

Comment: Update the question with the complete error stack trace.

Comment: can you provide a brief description how and where to get the full trace? Thanks in advance

Comment: I am one step further: the password contains of letters and an exclamation mark. If I let the driver enter the letters in front of the exclamation mark, enter the exclamation mark itself by keyboard and complete the password with the routine again, the login is successful. I suspect something with ASCII vs unicode. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this.
If your password was password, that is 8 characters, so you can use if len("passord") = 8 to check if the full password was entered.

```
Do until Len(MyChromeDriver.FindElementById("PasswordTextBox").Value) = 8
    MyChromeDriver.FindElementById("Password").Clear
    MyChromeDriver.FindElementById("Password").SendKeys "password"
Loop
```

Comment: I finally changed the password and replaced the exclamation mark with a dash and - guess what - it is working now without any problems. Although I still have no idea where the difference between the 2 characters should be, the problem is solved (at least for me). But thanks to KNAPPYFLASH for providing a possible solution.